# git insists in telling me "Already up-to-date.", What should I do?

Tags: git

I am new to git, and I am working on a project with a friend, and somewhere something went wrong, and I cannot fix it.

The state now is that I have a working copy on my computer, but when I run `git pull` or `git fetch` and then `git merge` I get the output `Already up-to-date.`. On the other hand when I make a new directory, and run a `git clone ... ..` I get a broken copy of the project. I have checked out branchings but I have only one `master` branch. Here are some commands so you may spot what I am missing.

```
$ git branch
* master
$ git pull
Password: 
Already up-to-date.
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .DS_Store
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$
```

Here is a branching image from bitbucket:
[image]

What I want to do is either uploading what I have, and run over everything on the server. Or merger 20bc5e1 with e5dd998.

I have tried this:

```
$ git branch friend 20bc5e1
$ git branch
* master
  friend
$ git merge friend
Already up-to-date.
```

So I had no success with this.

## Edit

After some head banging, I made the most simple thing: I inserted a new trivial change (added a letter in a comment), and then committed, then pushed. And something wired happened, when I opened a new folder and cloned the project again, I got back the latest working version. But when I checked that comment, the new letter was not there. Its simple one commit behind. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you do a "git push --force" at any point? Because it seems 1d9 completely replaced 20b. I would make a branch on e5d (current top master), reset master to origin/master (20b), and merge. Then push, and check that the other developer get back your work.

Comment: No I didn't do that. But after some thinking I remember having a conflict that I resolved. I was the 1d9 push where I did that. This explains some of my confusion.

Comment: I would still recommend a reset, re-applying your work on top of that reset.